# Python lists of lists order of operations

Tags: python, list, matrix

Here's a list of lists:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

To get the number 4 from the variable 'a', I would call `a[1][0]` but if instead of numbers what if they were lists:

```
a = [[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]], [[7],[8],[9]]]
```

To get the number 4 now, would it be `a[0][1][0]` or `a[1][0][0]`?

I know I can play around with it to figure this out but I am looking for some one to explain how Python is actually approaching the order of operation in fetching the number from a list of lists.

Answer (score 8):

Python evaluates expressions like `a[1][0][0]` from left to right. The parts of this expression are:

1. `a` which is the list `[[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]],[[7],[8],[9]]]`
2. `a[1]` which is the list `[[4],[5],[6]]`
3. `a[1][0]` which is the list `[4]`
4. `a[1][0][0]` which is the integer `4`.

Answer (score 3):

Outermost to innermost -

`a[1]` is `[[4], [5], [6]]`

`a[1][0]` is `[4]`

`a[1][0][0]` is `4`

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = [[[1],[2],[3]],[[4],[5],[6]],[[7],[8],[9]]]
>>> a[1]
[[4], [5], [6]]
>>> a[1][0]
[4]
>>> a[1][0][0]
4
```

What isn't clear here? Lists are nested. A list may contain other lists. The subscript syntax `list[n]` means "nth element of list". Which can be a list itself. So `list[n][m]` is the "mth elemtn of `list[n]`", and so on and so forth.